# Amcharts with verbose JSON

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts

[{"SUM_PTS":{"datatype":"INTEGER","length":"8","value":"29903727","obfuscated":"false"},"SUM_TOTAL":{"datatype":"INTEGER","length":"10","value":"1644704985","obfuscated":"false"},"MID":{"datatype":"ALPHANUMERIC","length":"27","value":"Vendor 1","obfuscated":"false"}},{"SUM_PTS":{"datatype":"INTEGER","length":"7","value":"3283570","obfuscated":"false"},"SUM_TOTAL":{"datatype":"INTEGER","length":"9","value":"180596350","obfuscated":"false"},"MID":{"datatype":"ALPHANUMERIC","length":"23","value":"Vendor 2","obfuscated":"false"}}]

Considering the above verbose JSON, how do I assign the valueField and titleField?

SUM_PTS and MID do not seem to work. I think it is because my JSON is more verbose than that used in the examples. I cannot change the JSON however, I need to resolve in the Amcharts Javascript.

Comment: AmCharts can't read nested JSON, so you're going to have to remap your data before passing it to AmCharts anyway. You can do it in JavaScript if you can't change the web service. If you point out what is meant to be your title field and value field, I can show how to remap it so that it works with whichever chart you're trying to use.

Comment: Thanks @xorspark. The title field would be the value of MID and the value field would be the value of SUM_PTS.

Comment: Thanks for the info. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SUM_PTS contains your value, and MID contains your title, mapping it to a simplified dataProvider format is pretty straightforward:

```
//assuming rawJson contains the above data:

var dataProvider = rawJson.map(function(jsonObj) {
  return {
    "title": jsonObj.MID.value,
    "value": jsonObj.SUM_PTS.value
  }
});
```

Here is your remapped data expressed as a pie chart for demonstration purposes:

```js
var rawJson = [{
 "SUM_PTS": {
  "datatype": "INTEGER",
  "length": "8",
  "value": "29903727",
  "obfuscated": "false"
 },
 "SUM_TOTAL": {
  "datatype": "INTEGER",
  "length": "10",
  "value": "1644704985",
  "obfuscated": "false"
 },
 "MID": {
  "datatype": "ALPHANUMERIC",
  "length": "27",
  "value": "Vendor 1",
  "obfuscated": "false"
 }
}, {
 "SUM_PTS": {
  "datatype": "INTEGER",
  "length": "7",
  "value": "3283570",
  "obfuscated": "false"
 },
 "SUM_TOTAL": {
  "datatype": "INTEGER",
  "length": "9",
  "value": "180596350",
  "obfuscated": "false"
 },
 "MID": {
  "datatype": "ALPHANUMERIC",
  "length": "23",
  "value": "Vendor 2",
  "obfuscated": "false"
 }
}]

var dataProvider = rawJson.map(function(jsonObj) {
  return {
    "title": jsonObj.MID.value,
    "value": jsonObj.SUM_PTS.value
  }
});

AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "titleField": "title",
  "valueField": "value",
  "dataProvider": dataProvider
})
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 300px"></div>
```

Comment: Many thanks @xorspark. I am also using a dataloader to load the JSON from a url. Any pointers on combining dataprovider with dataloader?

Comment: You can use [the postProcess callback](https://github.com/amcharts/dataloader/#complete-list-of-available-dataloader-settings) in the dataLoader to perform the same map action in my demo on the first parameter it passes and return the re-mapped array, i.e. `dataLoader: { url: /* your url here */, postProcess: function(rawJson) { /* map code here, return resulting array */ } }`